# View Shifts on UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController with a first view that is inside a navigation controller.  When the view is first displayed the nav bar covers the top part of the view.  As soon as I start to swipe the page, the view drops below the nav bar.  From then on the view will layout correctly.  How can I fix this?  What is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. To fix it, set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to NO before calling -setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
[self setViewControllers:@[firstPageViewController]
               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                animated:NO
              completion:NULL];
```